# Playstore not showing updated App Version to Users

Tags: android, google-play, google-developers-console, android-app-bundle

I have published an BETA build for 100% users, and later I promoted it to production for 100% users.
I have upgraded by SDK to 33 after playstore target SDK warning for 31st august 2023.

None of my users are able to see updated app version now, playstore is still showing last uploaded production app.

I tried filling all the app policies, but still not able to see update in playstore on any device.

Can anyone please help me on this.